# Strange behavior with JQuery show - Order of buttons determins if button is shown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have never seen this type of behavior before. JQuery will not show the delete button when the row is clicked unless I reorder the html buttons.

I have my buttons in the desired order as such:

```
<button type="button" id="blog-save" class="green">Save</button>
<button type="button" id="blog-reset">Reset</button>
<button type="button" id="blog-delete" class="red">Delete</button>
```

My css looks like this:

```
#blog-delete{ 
  display:none 
}
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#blog td:first-child', function(e){
  $("#blog-delete").show();
});
```

A row is simply this:

```
<tr id="11">
 <td>left column</td>
 <td>right comumn</td>
</tr>
```

When the user clicks a td row, AJAX loads the data into the form and displays the delete button. Even if I remove the AJAX call, the button will not be shown unless I reorder the buttons like this:

```
<button type="button" id="blog-delete" class="red">Delete</button>
<button type="button" id="blog-save" class="green">Save</button>
<button type="button" id="blog-reset">Reset</button>
```

Also, this behavior is **only present on Android and iOS mobile devices**. On FF, Chrome and others, it's fine.

Does anyone have any idea as to why the order is important here? I can reorder the buttons but that's not the point, I want to know what's causing this. It's not right.

**EDIT**

I just commented out the `display:none` in the css and I can see the delete button fine. Also, while the button is commented out in the css, I can add `$("#blog-delete").hide();` in the javascript and the button will hide but it will not come back when I click the row.

Comment: @null, thanks. I had a typo in my post. It was already `display:none;`. Good catch though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
'#blog td:first-child'
```

Will make it look for the first child under `td` so the rest of your code:

```
$('body').on('click', '#blog td:first-child', function(e){
    $("#blog-delete").show();
});
```

Will make it to where it shows only the first child.